# What is the difference between “penser” and “croire”?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I am confused about the difference between *penser* and *croire*.

In one of the lessons in Pimsleur, one is asked to translate the following conversion.

> Q: Who plays better tennis, him or her?
>   A: I think he plays better tennis.

I would have translated the reply as "Je crois que ..." but Pimsleur translates this as "Je pense que ...". Which of the two forms is correct? When does one use one over the other?

Comment: We could have literally the same question in SE Philosphy, and yet it would be totally another question.

Comment: Attention à la différence entre *croire que* et *croire en*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When formulating an opinion, both verbs are correct.

The difference between the two is that *penser* means *to think* and *croire* means *to believe*. Both can express an opinion, although the latter is a little bit firmer than the former.

Comment: As such, I'd tend to say that _croire_ is to express your own belief, while _penser_ is usually not about your opinion, but about something you believe may be true. So whether you feel it's personnal or not is going to help you decide which verb to use. If you express an opinion, _croire_ makes more sense (_Je crois que tu manges trop_); if you want to speak about a fact but show that you're not certain about it, use _penser_ (_Je pense qu'il est 4 heures_). But yes, most of the time both are quite valid, the only exception I can think of is that you won't say _Je pense en Dieu_.

Comment: @Joubarc: ton exemple avec le crédo est un example plutôt de «croire en», un autre example serait «il croit en ses chances».  On pourrait très bien dire «je crois/pense que Dieu existe» bien qu'avec «penser» la phrase semble un peu bizarre.

Answer (score 8):

Croire implique une chose imaginable que l'on ne peut démontrer, par dérivation, on croit qu'une idée est bonne, on émet une hypothèse, … ensuite on y *pense*, c'est-à-dire que l'on va vérifier si cette dernière est réalisable ou a une solution dans le réel.

Penser confronte la réflexion et la Raison à un objet tangible.

Le fait de croire est l'acceptation d'une situation, d'un concept extérieur que l'on ne connaît pas, qui ne laisse pas prise à l'un des cinq sens.

Le fait de penser est une projection de soi vers l'extérieur, pour aller chercher une vérité ou sa négation.

Vous aurez le temps de vous poser ces questions avant de faire un thème, mais oralement, beaucoup de gens échangent ces deux termes qui deviennent synonymes d'une incertitude sur ce qui va suivre lorsque la phrase est interrogative comme dans l'exemple du joueur de tennis. La nuance :

- si je suis persuadé que l'un est plus fort que l'autre, je *pense* que…
- si je n'arrive pas à me décider, mais qu'il y a un léger avantage, je *crois* que…

En revanche :

- « *je pense* que tu devrais faire ceci », est un conseil impératif,
- « *je crois* qu'il serait bien que tu fasses cela », est une pression amicale.

Mais l'intonation de la voix, l'expression corporelle, l'emporte, quel que soit le verbe choisi.

Sorry, no able to write it in English.

Comment: En lisant ta réponse, et en se rappelant la citation de Victor Hugo « Aimer, c'est la moitié de croire. », on a envie d'ajouter « ...et croire c'est la moitié de penser. » !

Comment: @RomainVALERI Hors du contexte de la réponse, *croire* sous entend une peur de l'inconnu[e], dont celle de la mort est la principale racine des religions. Croire met en route l'imaginaire pour trouver des solutions qui n'existe pas dans le réel, comme les mathématiques avec l'ensemble iR. *Penser* confronte la raison aux objets, aux faits et même aux artefacts. Penser ne résout pas l'ambivalence des mots et butte contre l'émotion, l'inexplicable, la relativité de la vérité qui ne peut atteindre l'absolu qu'avec une théorie basée sur la dualité instable par nature...

Comment: ... Reste *réaliser* qui unit un sujet à la réalité, dans l’ici et maintenant… problème de sagesse qui engage l’expérience.